# Are legislation based questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

We've had a few questions on legislation based issues, such as this recent one:

https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11903/is-pre-1975-california-smog-exemption-established-by-vin-only

I tend to mark them as off-topic, as they are very localised, and not really about maintenance and repair, but I was wondering what other people thought?

Answer (score 4):

It should depend on the nature of the question.

If a question is purely about the law, then yes it is off-topic for not being about maintenance and repair.

However, if someone is restoring a vehicle then, to pass the annual safety & emissions tests it must comply with those laws in force at the time of its manufacture.  At least, this is true in those jurisdictions that I know of.
So a question like *Do I need seat belts in the back seat of my 1967 Ford Cortina?* or *Should I fit chrome or rubber bumpers to my 1976 MGB GT?* should be on topic.

The catch is that such questions must state all relevant information, including the intended area of use.  This is likely to rule out a lot of questions if the poster doesn't word them carefully.